# output of oracle query result on prompt (bash script execution)

Tags: oracle, bash

while writing a bash script is there any way, not to display the out put of the query executed.

```
id1=`sqlplus -s user/pwd@SID <<EOF
    update udc_backup set user_id=${id} where user_name='${i}';
    commit;
    exit;
EOF`
```

shows "3 rows updated" on the prompt. 
Is there any way we can avoid printing such details.
Another query, When I tried to do some operations on the select query result(for e.g. if else check on the result of select) and "No rows selected" for the query, it show [: rows: unknown operator error on the prompt.
if [ $id -gt 0 ]
where id is the result of select query.
Could you please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use grep -v to filter out the undesired output. Quote the variable inside the if statement or use [[ instead of [

Answer (score 0):

SQLplus has quite a few options that you can set on or off. I believe the particular option you are looking for is:

```
set feedback off
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#sthref1916

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked with set feedback off option and if condition change